# WordPress | Date not always appear

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I try to create a theme. In that theme I have create a custom post type and I quering the WordPress by using the wp_query to get the posts from that post type with the code that following :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  18
);

$projects = new WP_Query($args);

while($projects->have_posts())
{
    $projects->the_post();
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<span><?php the_date(); ?></span>
<?php
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

the problem is, that while I get the title for all of my posts, I do not get the date for all of my posts. Some posts have the date, other they don't

Any idea for that issue ?

Comment: Do you still experience the issue when you replace the_date() with the_time()?

Comment: no, I tryed now the the_time() and that workes fine, but the date not. What's wrong with that ?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/59391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `the_date()` with `the_time()` and specify a date format like so:

```
the_time('l, F j, Y');
```

Check out [the codex article on formatting your date](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).